# Logging to Oracle Application server log files

Tags: logging, oas

I have an application that works fine on tomcat, but when I deployed it on Oracle Application Server, I get some errors.

I need to log some values in my code but cannot do that...

When I write `System.out.println("bla bla")` in my code, I couldn't see that msg on the log files

Why that?

NOTE, I am taking about application log files http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B32110_01/core.1013/b32196/log.htm#i1016126

Answer (score 0):

System.err and System.out messages are redirected to the OC4J logs.
See the screenshot in the link you attached above.
Under OC4J you should see the home/instance used be the application. There you will see the system error and system output logs.

EDIT: you can also view the logs from the filesystem at: $ORACLE_HOME/j2ee/instance_name/log

Comment: I tried to System.out and System.err but cannot see any thing! Also I don't have access to that machine... I have did a simple servlet that is hosted on my machine, and made the application log to this servlet!

Comment: I don't fully understand: the Oracle Application Server is installed on a machine you don't have access to (in filesystem terms). So how is the simple servlet hosted on your machine? didn't you deploy it to the server?